hyperref Textfield Output of default value from input field
I have a document with a lot of \TextField input text fields where the user is supposed to add some values. Later in the document I am using a read-only \TextField to output the previously set values. This works fine.
However, I sometimes put a default value/initial value for the input textfield and this is not automatically displayed in the output text field. Is this somehow achievable? I know I can set a separate default value on the output field, but I basically always want to display what is set in the input text field - before and after a user entered something.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \Form

    Input text field:
    \TextField[
        name=input,
        width=3in,
        default="default value of input",
        value ="value that is not the default" %overrides the default value
    ]{}

    Output text field:
    \TextField[
        name=output-field,
        width=3in,
        readonly=true,
        default="default value of output",
        calculate = {
        event.value = "prefix_" + this.getField("input").value;
        }
    ]{}


\end{document}

Second question along these lines: is there a difference in using default and value (initial value as per documentation) if it can anyhow be modified by the user?
Thank you in advance
